# Identifying the missing number in an array

Tags: algorithm, ruby

This is from [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/missing-number/):

> Missing Number
>
> Given an array containing n distinct numbers taken from 0, 1, 2, ...,
>   n, find the one that is missing from the array.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: [3,0,1]
>   Output: 2
>
> Example 2:
>
> Input: [9,6,4,2,3,5,7,0,1]
>   Output: 8
>
> Note: Your algorithm should run
>   in linear runtime complexity. Could you implement it using only
>   constant extra space complexity?

Code:

```
def missing_number(nums)
    nums.empty? ? 0 : nums.inject(:^)^(1..nums.length).inject(:^)
end
```